# Bcryptjs x Bun.hash

Tags: hash, bcrypt, bun

I'm working on a project in Bun based on a Moodle foundation, in PostgreSQL. The stored password hash is generated using the password_hash function (PHP) using the bcrypt algorithm.

Initially, I tried to use Bun's hash library to compare the password sent by the request and the stored hash, but with Bun it doesn't work at all. On the other hand, I tested it with the compare function of the bcryptjs library and succeeded in the endeavor.

With Bun, I tested the following, and it didn't match:

```js
const isMatch = await Bun.password.verify(password, hash);
```

With bcryptjs, I tested with the following code and it worked:

```js
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, hash)
```

Is it a bug in Bun or is it my mistake?

Comment: What type of password hash is it? Usually in the beginning there’s the type with a number between dollar signs (for example $6$ or $2a$ etc). There’s an open ticket in Bun for some types that aren’t handled correctly so might be one of them.

Comment: Hello, you're welcome!

The hash begins with $2y$, indicating that bcrypt was used to calculate the hash.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php#constant.password-bcrypt

Comment: Then it might very well be this problem in Bun https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/9078